# Android Studio always stopping at Starting LLDB server

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I work in Android Studio. 
I did all step which take official site. But when I start debug I see line

> Starting LLDB server

And he does not finish. I wait 30 min but he does not finish.
What I must to do. Because I think this bug or I must to take some settings.

If I debug java code use java debugger all work good.

> Starting LLDB server:
>   /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh
>   /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb unix-abstract
>   /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb/tmp platform-1524470360668.sock "lldb
>   process:gdb-remote packets"